# how to access skydrive other users shared folders and files using C# WP7

Tags: c#, windows, live, shared, onedrive

I have been able to play with user's own folders and files in skydrive using C# apis. But I can't figure out how to access other users shared files and folders. I tried to use folder id, url link etc. but no success.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is hidden in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/jj680723.aspx under

"Getting a list of SkyDrive objects that are shared with the signed-in user"